# Powershell: How can I get a list of Environment Variables with their values AND types (machine or user) from ALL user-profiles?

Tags: windows, powershell, types, environment-variables

in Powershell I want to get a list of Environment Variables with their values AND types (machine or user) from ALL user-profiles.

If I use

```
gci env:
```

I'll get all environment variables that are currently set, but I can't see which variable of those is set for the machine and which variable is set for user.
And of course I can't see ALL environment variables that are (or have been) set from any users that are working on the current computer (Win10).

Is there a way how such a listing can be coded in Powershell?

Comment: There are three scopes 1) Machine 2) User 3) Process (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.4#long-description)   So you can use scope property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.4#managing-scope

Comment: This answer gives some pointers re HLKM vs HKCU environment variables. You can also check "HKEY_USERS:\<user_sid>\Environment" for other users if your account has permissions... stackoverflow.com/questions/573817/…

Comment: The variables themselves don't "know" where they're sourced from. They could as well have been set manually from userspace after process creation

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen:
Yes, of course they don't "know", thanks for that thought, but that's not helping matters ;-)

Comment: @mclayton: Yes, my account has the needed permissions, thx for that thought, I'll have a look into it.

Comment: @jdweng: Thanks for that thought, I'll have a look into this issue in connection of what mclayton wrote.

Comment: I would not use the Registry (HKEY_USERS) to get the results when you can get from PS.

Comment: You would have to mount every user's ntuser.dat hive in the registry.

Comment: Why are you trying to enumerate env vars set for other users? What about env vars for processes owned by other users that are not machine or user env vars? It is unclear what you are trying to do. The source of an env var for the current process isn't really relevant. Your question is incoherent. I don't think anyone can correctly answer your question because it is very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @KurtisRader: Well, mklement0 not only grasped my intention, he offered a brilliant solution, so much for incoherency of my question ... - please re-read my question, I haven't even mentioned env vars for processes.
By the way, I agree with one aspect of your comment:
The source of an env var (only) for the current process isn't really relevant, at least not for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Preface:

Note that this answer fundamentally applies to *Windows only*.

- The *machine*-scope environment variables, as persistently defined in the registry, can be obtained via [`[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables), which returns an unordered dictionary of environment-variable name-value pairs:
  `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables('Machine')`

  - By definition, these definitions are *shared by all user accounts*.
- For the *current user only*, the *user*-scope environment variables, as persistently defined in the registry, can be obtained with
  `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables('User')`
- Any given *process* sees a *composite* of these two scopes (for the user in whose context the process is created):

  - While `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables('Process')` can be used to retrieve the process-scope variables, in PowerShell it is simplest to use `Get-ChildItem Env:`, which has the added advantage of returning the variables *sorted by name*.
  - Similarly, to access a given process-scope variable by name in PowerShell, it simplest to use [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375), e.g. `$env:OS` for variable `OS` - see the conceptual [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables) help topic.
  - While user-scope environment variable generally *override* machine-scope ones of the same name, the `PATH` environment is special: its effective value is the *concatenation* of the machine- and user-scope values, *in that order*.

Note:

- It follows from the above that the ***user* and *machine* scopes exclusively relate to *persisted* (persistently predefined) environment variables**, which *in combination* form the *runtime* process scope, often *indirectly*, by inheriting the parent process' process-scope environment. At the process level, you cannot reliably tell which persisted scope - if any - a given value came from: it may be a value created or modified by a parent process, or it may be a composite value merging the user- and machine-scope values, as in the case of `PATH`. Additionally, there are the so-called *volatile* (non-persisted, dynamic) environment variables such as `USERPROFILE` and `APPDATA` that are created on demand *at user login*.
- **All methods above report *expanded* environment-variable values**, i.e. any *nested* environment variable references in persisted-in-the-registry definitions using `REG_EXPAND_SZ` registry values were expanded to their values.
- As of this writing (.NET 8 / PowerShell (Core) 7.4.x), neither the [`[System.Environment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment) .NET API nor PowerShell's [`Environment` provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Provider) support getting or setting *unexpanded* values.
- Doing the latter requires working directly with the [*.NET registry APIs*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.Win32.Registry); e.g., the following retrieves the unexpanded definition of the current user's `TEMP` environment variable:

  ```bash
  # -> '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp' - note the nested %USERPROFILE% reference.
  (Get-Item -Path HKCU:\Environment).GetValue('TEMP', $null, 'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')
  ```
- The problematic absence of support for *unexpanded* environment-variable values in the dedicated APIs is the subject of:

  - .NET: [GitHub issue #1442](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1442)
  - PowerShell: [GitHub issue #16812](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16812)

---

###### Getting *user*-scope environment variables *across all local user profiles*:

- The solution below **gets the *persistently defined* user-scope environment variables** from all local user profiles.

  - Any process is free to modify its inherited persisted environment at runtime. To get the *runtime*, process-scope environment variables of a given process programmatically, nontrivial effort via system (WinAPI) calls is needed; this [C++-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63222041/45375) may offer a solution. *Interactively*, you can use SysInternals' [Process Explorer (`procexp.exe`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) utility, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1202697/45375).
    Either way you need to run *with elevation*, as without it you'll only be able to inspect your own, non-elevated processes.
- As [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) notes, in order to **access *other users'* persistently defined user-scope environment variable definitions**, you must **explicitly load their profiles into the registry**, via the (hidden) `ntuser.dat` file in the respective profile directories.
- Doing so **requires *elevation*** (running as administrator).

The following code demonstrates this approach:

- It - temporarily - loads other users' local profiles into the `HKEY_USERS` registry hive on demand, into a subkey name for each user's [SID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier) in order to extract the target user's user-scope environment-variables.

  - For simplicity, it does so with the help of [`reg.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg) `load` / `unload` - there may be faster, in-process techniques to achieve the same.
- It outputs a sorted dictionary, keyed by *username*, with each entry containing a nested dictionary of environment-variable key-value pairs for that user.

  - E.g., to query the (unexpanded) `TEMP` variable definition of user `jdoe`, use the following:

    ```bash
    $userEnvironments['jdoe'].TEMP
    ```
- Note:

  - The **reported values are *unexpanded* values**; that is, nested environment-variable references are *not* expanded.
  - Doing the latter *properly* would require nontrivial additional effort, as  the code doing the expansion would have to take the *target user*'s environment into account; by contrast, using expansion in the *caller*'s environment will lead to false results.

    - E.g., caller `jdoe` asking for `jsmith`'s definition of `TEMP` and doing expansion of `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` in the context of `jdoe`, will incorrectly report `C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Temp` rather than `C:\Users\jsmith\AppData\Local\Temp`

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# Initialize the result dictionary.
$userEnvironments = [System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary[string, System.Collections.IDictionary]]::new()

# Process all local user local profiles.
Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $sid = $_.Sid
    $userName = try {
     (([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] $sid).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value -split '\\')[-1]
    } catch {
      # SID doesn't identify an existing user account -> ignore it.
      return 
    }
    # See if the target user's registry hive is already loaded, which is
    # only the case for the current user, system accounts, and service accounts.
    $userHivePath = "registry::HKEY_USERS\$sid"
    if ($mustLoad = -not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $userHivePath)) {
      $localProfilePath = Join-Path $_.LocalPath ntuser.dat
      Write-Verbose "Loading registry hive for user $sid from $localProfilePath..."
      reg.exe load "HKU\$sid" $localProfilePath >$null
      if ($LASTEXITCODE) { throw "reg.exe load failed with error code $LASTEXITCODE" }
    }
    # Create a sorted dictionary with the environment-variable key-value pairs.
    $envVars = [System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary[string, string]]::new()        
    $regKey = Get-Item -LiteralPath "registry::HKEY_USERS\$sid\Environment"
    $regKey.GetValueNames() |
      ForEach-Object { $envVars[$_] = $regKey.GetValue($_, $null, 'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames') }
    $regKey.Close() # Necessary to allow unloading.
      # Add it to the result dictionary, keyed by username. 
    $userEnvironments[$userName] = $envVars
    # Unload the registry hive again, if it had to be loaded on demand.
    if ($mustLoad) {
      Write-Verbose "Unloading registry hive of user $sid..."
      reg.exe unload "HKU\$sid" >$null
      if ($LASTEXITCODE) { throw "reg.exe unload failed with error code $LASTEXITCODE" }
    }
    }

# Output the result dictionary.
# To access, e.g., user "jdoe"'s environment variable, use:
#      $userEnvironments['jdoe']
# To get a given user's specific variable's value, e.g. 'TEMP'
#      $userEnvironments['jdoe'].TEMP
$userEnvironments
```

Comment: WOW - I am deeply impressed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use .NET here to get the environment variables per scope as Hashtables:

**User scope**

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables([System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```

**Machine scope**

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables([System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

**Process scope**

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables([System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
```

Comment: ➕1, but note the added requirement: "from ALL user-profiles".